# How to target div relative to buttons in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to make a script that will hide/show divs right under inputs. At the moment, I am targeting every single inputs and every single divs by ID (which I find might be a bit heavy, instead of targeting divs relatively to the input position).

So right now it looks a bit like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#inputbutton1').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#divtarget1').toggle('show');
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#inputbutton2').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#divtarget2').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

and so on. Is there a way I could take, say, the event.target and from there, reach the div **relative** to that input button. So that way I would have a single script with variable values rather than 30 scripts with unique ID selectors. Each input button/div combos come as follows (They are scattered through the page, but always come in pairs.) :

```
<div class="hideshowdiv"><input class="hideshowbtn" type='button' id='inputbutton1' value='Hide/Show Image'></div>
<div id="divtarget1" class="spellimg"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Image"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code. It's flexible and will work for every new image you add.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideshowdiv">
  <input class="hideshowbtn" type='button' id='inputbutton1' value='Hide/Show Image'>
</div>
<div id="divtarget1" class="spellimg">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>

<div class="hideshowdiv">
  <input class="hideshowbtn" type='button' id='inputbutton1' value='Hide/Show Image'>
</div>
<div id="divtarget1" class="spellimg">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>

<div class="hideshowdiv">
  <input class="hideshowbtn" type='button' id='inputbutton1' value='Hide/Show Image'>
</div>
<div id="divtarget1" class="spellimg">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I was trying to use event.target, but it didn't work at all, I didn't think that "this" would target the clicked element :) .

Comment: @Kleinaroo Great to hear :)

Comment: You could add a class to the specific types of inputs that you want this to happen for (in case there are other inputs on the page).